# Passing file stream from WCF to asmx web service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am trying to pass a file from WCF to asmx web service. I have added reference of asmx service in WCF project... when I call the function in web service it shows the error

> cannot convert from System.IO.FileStream to WcfLayer.ServiceReference1.File Stream

The function definition in web service is

```
[WebMethod]
public void Import(FileStream fs)
{
}
```

Function call is

```
  FileStream fStream = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Create);
  ServiceReference1.ImportXliffSoapClient client = new  ServiceReference1.ImportXliffSoapClient();
  client.Import(fStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Stream` instead of `FileStream`, as the parameter for the web service.

Also, what is happening is you are not re-using existing types. The proxy is generating new types for the parameters.

In this case, in the options to add a web service, there should be an option to 'Re-use assemblies from XX' radio button. This way it will not generate new types, but use the targeted ones you have specified.